# Can't connect remote MySql server

Tags: php, mysql

I have some troubles to connect to a remote mysql server.

This is the situation :

- I have 1 MySql server which is working (Installed phpMyAdmin, and can do actions on it).
- I have 1 webserver

I try to access to my mysql server with the mysql_connect(); function :

```
$host    = 'my_ip:ext_port';
$user    = 'leUser';
$pass    = 'lePassword';
$mydb    = 'leDb';

$db = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
```

Where ext_port is the port I open in my MySql server and which redirect to the port 3306.

I also give to my user the access with :

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'leUser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*lePasswordEncrypted'  WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Tried a lot of things in vain (As comment the line bind-address in my.cnf, etc ...) but still get the error :

**Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx' (4)**

Comment: In your PHP example, you have `lePassword` whereas in the SQL you have `*lePasswordEncrypted`; are they actually the same?

Comment: Have you specified the `mysql.user.host` value for *leUser* ? (e.g. are they allowed access from your web server IP)

Comment: can't connect means it literally can't connect. wrong ip/port and/or firewall. If it was permissions issue it'd says "permission denied"

Comment: @MarcB - good point, could be a firewall issue

Comment: @newfurniturey : Yes, except that lePassword is not encrpyted. (I copy the password of root user (Which I know) to make the Grant request.

Comment: @CD001 : I don't know, don't know what is is file ... I'll look at. And in the firewall I allow port I use to redirect to 3306

Comment: @MarcB : Maybe, but I open port, I'm sure of the IP.

Comment: can you do a `telnet ip.of.server 3306` at the command line of your client machine and get a connection? If that times out as well, then you've got a network issue of some sort.

Comment: `mysql.user.host` isn't in a file it's the `host` column of the `user` privileges table on the `mysql` database ... but as @MarcB says - that would result in a *permission denied* error rather than a *could not connect* error.

Comment: I guess to 99%  this is caused by the server not listening for eternal connections. See `bind-address` directive in MySQL's my.cnf http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address

Comment: @CD001 : The column host for leUser is * (I tried also with %)

Comment: @MarcB : I tried telnet connection from the console of my webserver to try join the mysql server by using mysqlserver.ip 7755 (7755 which is the external port which redirect to 3306).

Comment: @johannes I tried to modify the bind-adress by adding 0.0.0.0, but change nothing